# Get current item in loop in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008, sql-update

If I write loop in SQL like:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0 

SET @length = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table)

WHILE @Counter <= @length
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id INT = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM table WHERE id = @Counter)
    DECLARE @someValue int = (SELECT TOP 1 someValue FROM table WHERE id = @id)
END
```

I never wrote loop in SQL before and what I need is to take values from current item in loop and use it.

In code above I use `SELECT` to get `someValue`.

Do I need to make `select` like this for all fields I need or there is some easier way something like foreach loop and get current `item.someValue`?

**UPDATE**

Based on comments maybe I don't need loop.

This is example table

```
create table products 
(
    tourId int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    title nvarchar(50),
    orderTime smalldatetime,
    orderSecondTime smalldatetime,
    orderThirdTime smalldatetime
);
```

`orderTime` has value, `orderSecondTime` and `orderThirdTime` are `NULL`.

I need to make some `CASE..WHEN` on `orderTime` and update `orderSecondTime` and `orderThirdTime`.

When I say `CASE...WHEN` I need based on date in orderTime update other columns  like:

`orderThirdTime` can depend on `orderSecondTime` this is where I thought loops are natural solution.

Those other columns are basically add `orderSecondTime = 24h + orderTime` `orderThirdTime = orderTime to orderSecondTime` and similar.

**UPDATE #2**:

Example rules:

In case that orderTime is between 08:00 and 10:00 :

- orderSecondTime = orderTime + 60 min
- orderThirdTime = orderSecondTime(calculated above) + 60 min
- ELSE use different calculation like add 30 min

What I have

[image]

```
tourId  title   orderTime           orderSecondTime orderThirdTime
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1       prod1   2020-08-02 08:00    null            null
2       prod12  2020-08-02 09:00    null            null
3       prod13  2020-08-02 10:00    null            null
4       prod14  2020-08-02 11:00    null            null
```

What I am trying to calculate

[image]

Comment: As it stands, this code makes little sense. An explanation of what you are trying to do would help.

Comment: I have table and I need to iterate through each row get some columns from each row to make other calculations inside loop. On each iteration I insert new row (with calculated values) in another table.

Comment: Why are you using a loop in the first place? SQL excels at set based methods, and a `WHILE` is the complete opposite of that.

Comment: You likely  don't need a loop for this. If you give us the full picture, then we might be able to suggest something more efficient than a loop.

Comment: I updated question with details about what I am trying to do and why I thought loop is solution for this case.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e47876f84ba0400f5080f74214b7bace
Is this helpful?

Comment: `rderThirdTime = orderTime to orderSecondTime`, what does this mean? As commented by DaleK, you would need to show us the results that you want.

Comment: `orderSecondTime = orderTime + 60min` now I need to user that value to calculate `orderThirdTime` which is result of (`orderSecondTime = orderTime + 60min`) and add `orderTime` to it

Comment: And I added some more details

Comment: FYI, data is much better presented as formatted text than as images - see the one I converted for you - you can just copy and paste from SSMS and then format as code - very quick.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you just after a couple of `CASE` expressions?

```
SELECT id,
       title,
       orderTime,
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(time,orderTime) >= '08:00' AND CONVERT(time,orderTime) <= '10:00' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 1, orderTime)
                                                                                           ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, orderTime)
       END AS orderSecondTime,
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(time,orderTime) >= '08:00' AND CONVERT(time,orderTime) <= '10:00' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 2, orderTime)
                                                                                           ELSE DATEADD(HOUR, 1, orderTime)
       END AS orderSecondTime
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

*Side Note: SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for over a year now. You should be looking at upgrade paths as soon as possible if not already.*

Comment: Then use an `UPDATE` statement with the same logic, @1110 ... The `CASE` expression are what you are after. You just start with `UPDATE dbo.YourTable` or `UPDATE {Table Alias}` instead of `SELECT...`.